# Preprocess function not running on theme

Tags: theming

I am trying to query my database and return a number to store in a twig template called `node--course.html.twig`.

So I started by writing the function `completionCheck()` in class `FormaRegis.php`.

```
namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;


class FormaRegis extends FormaEntity {

     public $ID;

  public function setID($ID) {
    $this->ID = $ID;
  }

  public function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
  }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


 public function rowBase() {


     if (parent::accessCheck()) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM learning_courseuser
                  WHERE idUser = " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'] .
                 " AND idCourse = " . $this->ID. " ";
        return $sql;
       } else {

            return "";
       }

    }

    public function completionCheck() {
        $check = false;

         if (parent::accessCheck()) {
            $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM learning_courseuser
                    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(date_complete,'%d/%m/%Y')
                    AND idUser =  " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'];

            return $sql;
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }

    }

}
```

and in a page called `FormaEntity.php` I wrote this function:

```
public function getCCresult() {
   if ($this->completionCheck() == "") {
      \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
      return false;
   }

   $result = $this->connection->query($this->completionCheck())->fetch();
     \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();

   if ($result > 5 ) {
     $check = "fail";
   }
   else {
     $check = "pass";
   }

   return $check;
}
```

Then in `FormaNotification.php` I wrote function `completionCheck()`.

```
namespace Drupal\docebo_login;

use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaEntity;

class FormaNotification extends FormaEntity {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getResult() {

         return parent::accessCheck();
    }

    public function completionCheck() {

         return parent::getCCresult();
    }

}
```

Then finally, in my `MYTHEME.theme` file I added the function `mytheme_preprocess_node_course(&$variables)`.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node_course (&$variables) {

  $noti = new FormaNotification();

  if ($noti->completionCheck() == "fail") {
    $variables['creditCheck'] = "yes";
  }
  else {
    $variables['creditCheck'] = "no";
  }

}
```

But when I visit the any page that uses the `node--course.html.twig` and use `{{ kint(creditCheck) }}`, it says that the variable is `NULL`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You’re not returning any renderable elements as far as I can see?

Comment: @kevin not $variables[“credit check”]?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance I am brand new to drupal

Comment: Not that it would solve your issue, but applying Drupal [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards) would at least make your code to be easier readable.

Comment: The preprocess function must have two underscores: `mytheme_preprocess_node__course`.

Comment: It always has to go like `template_preprocess_node__NODE_TYPE` and `template_preprocess_node__NODE_TYPE__VIEW_MODE` with two underscores.

Comment: @leymannx thats tsrange cause none of the functions in my theme file have two underscores. I should note there is already a function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables), and when I try to add: 

if ($noti->completionCheck() == "fail") {
    $variables['creditCheck'] = "yes";
  }
  else {
    $variables['creditCheck'] = "no";
  }


The site throw an error that i am overallocated the memory and when i assign more it just throws a 500 error

Comment: May be a problem with `completionCheck()`, but what happens when you add `$variables['creditCheck'] = 'running';`? Will this get passed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88511/discussion-between-mat-steuernagle-and-leymannx).